# C# folder.FolderPath (and many other dynamic properties)

Tags: outlook-redemption

I logon to an RDOSession, then:

```
foreach(RDOStore store in rdoSession.Stores)
    {
        RDOFolder folder = store.GetDefaultFolder(rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
        Debug.WriteLine(folder.FolderPath);
    }
```

Visual Studio marks FolderPath as an error: RDOFolder does not contain a definition for FolderPath...

If I omit that line (so the code will run), then break right after getting the folder, I can add folder to the watch list and expand it. It shows no properties at all unless I expand the Dynamic View node. I can then see all the properties referred to in the Redemption docs.

My question is: how do I refer to Redemption properties like FolderPath in code? Some properties are fine -- e.g. folder.Items will compile just fine. But many are not -- like folder.FolderPath.

Answer (score 1):

The `FolderPath` property is implemented by the `IRDOFolder2` interface and derived from `RDOFolder`. Try to cast an instance of the `RDOFolder`
class to `IRDOFolder2` and get the property value.

Also you may try using the Outlook object model which provides the [MAPIFolder.FolderPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mapifolder.folderpath?view=outlook-pia) property which returns a string (string in C#) that indicates the path of the current folder.